# Defining my spaceship movement in spritekit game in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Hi I am new to Xcode and Swift, right now I am trying to design a game that involves a spaceship as player with alien spaceships.
I ran into a little problem where I am trying to differentiate the movement of the spaceship from the firing of the spaceship.

Basically I used touchesBegan() function to run the function which my spaceship fires, and touchesMoved() function to move the spaceship's x-position.

These are the code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    pShoot()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        spaceship.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.5))

    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to differentiate the clicking or touching indicator and pressed and move indicator, in other words I dont want the spaceship to fire when I am pressed and move on the screen, and I do not want the spaceship to move when I am clicking constantly but at different position. ( touchesMoved() detects changes in touch positions so if I am clicking at different positions spaceship will move which I dont want)

I would like to know what would be the best way of implementing this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the area that the user pressed and deciding whether or not to move the spaceship depending on the origin of the touch.